# How can I use FileReader to load an image and set it as a background for thousands of divs efficiently?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Currently I'm using FileReader to load in a sprite sheet png from the user's system and save the data to an Image variable as its src. I then populate a separate div with over a thousand divs, each of them have a

```
style="background-image: url(' + loadedImage.src + ');
```

Which turns into:

```
style="background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAA...)"
```

in the element. The image can be quite large, and there can be up to 2048 of these images. This causes a lot of lag upon creation.

My limitations on this task is that I cannot make any calls to the server, the file upload and displaying has to all be on the front end. Otherwise, I would just save the file to the server and use CSS with a URL so that the browser can cache the image and use the styling onto all of the divs.

Is there a better way I can do this? Can I put in a global style for all elements with JS?

Comment: Well, StackOverflow for instance uses such a sprite-sheet. Rather than chopping it up into lots of pieces, it simply sizes the elements appropriately then uses an offset into the sheet to ensure the right part of the image is shown in each. You can find the spritesheet at: http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/share-sprite-new.svg?v=78be252218f3

Comment: The png that is being uploaded IS a spritesheet. In my question, the user is uploading the sheet (png) and then it is getting copied to other divs and then repositioned. My question is how do you copy the sheet (png) over many divs without making any server requests?

Comment: *Thousands* of divs? Are all of those divs on the screen at the same time?

Comment: Why are you using a file reader and if you are why aren't you drawing it from the cache?

Comment: @StevenRogers - Yes, I realize this - you already said that in the first line of your question. What on earth do server requests have to do with the question? You get the file and set it as the background image for a css rule that all of the divs share. You then give each of the divs an additional rule that positions the image. You said that there are upto 2048 of these images - what, 2048 sprite-sheets, or 2048 sprites in the sheet? You appear to either place a huge burden on the user or use language inconsistently.

Comment: Sorry, that's probably just my language. The user is going to upload a single image/spritesheet (.png) then the JS creates 2048 divs, each div with a background-image containing all of the image data and a background-position for each of the sprites. This displays all the sprites to the user. I did not know there was a way to add a style to the entire page using JS, so I was adding it to each div directly. Looking at the html through the chrome inspector, each div contained the entire data of the image (ouch). The answers below are what I was looking for.

Comment: @StevenRogers - :grins: No worries, I thought that was probably the case, but you know what they say about assumptions. Perfect. Glad to hear you've a nicer way of handling the data thanks to the solutions offered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could actually add a rule to an existing stylesheet after reading the image using the `FileReader` API.

Maybe something like this, would work. Just an idea.

```js
var sheet = document.styleSheets[1];

function fileReader(e) {
  if(window.FileReader) {
    var file  = e.target.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    if (file && file.type.match('image.*')) {
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    } else {
      console.log('please add an image')
    }
    reader.onloadend = function (e) {
      sheet.insertRule(".foo" + "{ background:url(" + reader.result + ")}", 0);
    }
  }
}

document.getElementById('add-img').addEventListener('change', fileReader, false);
```

```css
.foo {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="add-img" />
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="foo"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah you can add the CSS using this:

`document.styleSheets[0].insertRule('class="myClass" {background-image: url(' + loadedImage.src + '}', 0)`